# Command Button Invoke Action After Async JavaScript

Tags: visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

I have a page that prompts the user for information and may need to do multiple web service callouts. Each callout needs to do DML when complete, so I'm using Visualforce Remoting to perform those actions first. Once the actions are complete, I need to execute an Apex method to do some more work. This may be more of a JavaScript question, but hopefully someone has the answer.

Right now, the page doesn't wait for all the remoting calls to finish before invoking the action. How can I get it to wait?

My Button:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!buildFax}" onclick="checkForCharts(function(){return true});" value="Build Fax" />
```

My JS (somewhat simplified):

```
function getChart(client, accession, callback) { 
        PatientCharts.getPatientChartToSObjectRemote(
        '{!theCase.Id}',
        client,
        accession,
        function(result, event){
            callback(event);
        });
    }

    function checkForCharts(docallback) {
        // Async worker counters
        var workers = 0;

        function tickWorkers() {
            workers--;
            if ( workers === 0 ) {
                if (docallback)
                    docallback();
            }
        }

        j$('[id$="patTab"]')
            .find('input[type="checkbox"][name$="chart"]:checked').closest('tr')
            .each(function() {
                var client = j$(this).find('[id$="client"]').text();
                var accession = j$(this).find('[id$="accn"]').text();
                workers++;
                getChart(client, accession, function(eventres) {
                    tickWorkers();
                });

            })
```

Comment: Do the actions and callbacks need to be chained in a particular order or is it just at the very end after a bunch of parallel async calls that the apex needs to run?

Comment: Just after the async jobs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is `apex:actionFunction` to generate a JavaScript function bound to an APEX method that can be passed as a JavaScript callback.

Let's try to understand, what happens when pressing your button:

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!buildFax}" onclick="checkForCharts(function(){return true});" value="Build Fax" />
```

Of course, the `onclick` code is executed first. It means invoking `checkForCharts`, that correctly starts the asynchronous workers and returns no value. Then the returned value (in our case nothing, or rather the `undefined` constant) is checked:

- if it's *identical* to `false`, no further actions are executed,
- otherwise the `action` method is called normally.

Thus the method `buildFax` is called immediately after setting up workers, not waiting for evaluation of the callback.

After this long introduction, the fix is easy:

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!buildFax}" name="doBuildFax" />
<apex:commandButton value="Build Fax" onclick="checkForCharts(doBuildFax); return false;" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that is going to work, but there must be something wrong with my async worker logic. The callback is coming too early still.

Comment: Never mind. Copy paste error. All is working! Thanks for the great answer and explanations.